# How can I get an app bar to stay at the bottom regardless of screen resolution?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm building a Windows 8 App in c# and I cannot get an app bar to stay at the bottom of the screen.

I'm testing the program on a 2560x1440 PC monitor and a  1366x768 Windows surface. It fits perfectly (by default) to the Windows Surface device, but shows in the middle of the screen on the PC monitor.

Here's what I have:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     can.Height = user.screenHeight; //Can is a canvas, which is being drawn on to. 
     can.Width = user.screenWidth; //user class contains information about the current user of the program

     var resScale = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale;           
}
```

I can easily set the canvas as it covers the entire screen. But I'm unsure how to approach the appbar. I'm surprised there is not a property that will automaticly tag the bar to the bottom of the screen.

Here's the XAML for the app bar:

```
<AppBar x:Name="mainBar" Canvas.Top="700" Width="1366" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource NewWindowAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click_1" />
</AppBar>
```

Sorry if this has been asked. Just I've been searching around for ages and cannot find anything that will help me.

Thanks

Comment: A `Canvas` is not an appropiate container to layout your UI elements. Use a `Grid` or `DockPanel` or something

Comment: Put the Canvas in a Grid? I'm using the canvas because my program requires drawing to the window.

Comment: You're putting the `AppBar` inside the Canvas, that's wrong. Use a `Grid` or some other container that is intended for Layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not you try this. This will open app bar at the bottom of page regardless of screen resolution.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="mainBar" Padding="10,0,10,0" AutomationProperties.Name="Bottom App Bar" IsOpen="True">
         <Button Style="{StaticResource NewWindowAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click_1" />
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

if canvas is the requirement then you can set the width and height using this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
    can.Height = bounds.Height;
    can.Width = bounds.Width;
}
```

also try implementing the size changed event

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnWindowSizeChanged;
```

and applying the same there also